# magento 2.1 grid on custom tab of admin product edit page

Tags: product, module, grid, magento-2.1, custom

I am trying to create a grid that should be shown on clicking a custom tab of admin `catalog edit` page.

**1. Created catalog_product_new.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product_form">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Customtab" after="review" name="product.customtab" as="customtab" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custome Tab</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**2. Created Customtab.php**

```
<?php
namespace Venodr\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Customtab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/sample.phtml';
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_customtabFactory;
    public function __construct(
    Context $context, Registry $registry, \Vendor\Module\Model\CustomtabFactory $customtabFactory, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_customtabFactory = $customtabFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
    public function getCustomData($item_id) {
        $model = $this->_customtabFactory->create();
        $modelData = $model->getCollection();
        $modelData->addFilter('item_id', array('eq' => $item_id));

        $data = $modelData->getData();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**3. Created sample.phtml**

```
$product =  $block->getProduct();
$item_id = $product->getId();
$customdata =  $block->getCustomData($item_id);
foreach ($customdata as $key => $data) {
     echo $data['title'];  echo $data['created_time'];
}
```

By this way I am able to show my custom Tab on Admin `catalog edit` page , which shows `sample.phtml` content. But, I want to show grid instead of `sample.phtml`

Can anyone provide me the steps to show grid on custom tab created in `catalog_product_new.xml` ?